# При парсинге сайта столкнулся с тем что не могу вывести ссылки на питоне

Tags: python, python-3.x, парсер, beautiful-soup, веб-сайт

текст выводится а вот ссылки с сайта не получается что делать?
`хотел получить это: Человек-бензопила|https://animego.org/anime/chelovek-benzopila-2119` 
`а получил это: Человек-бензопила|https://animego.org/None`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as b


def get_first_anime ():
    headers={"user-agent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36"}
    url="https://animego.org/anime?sort=r.rating&direction=desc"
    r=requests.get(url=url, headers=headers)
    soup=b(r.text, 'html.parser')
    animes=soup.find_all("div", class_="animes-list-item media")
    for article in animes:
        anime_title=article.find("div",class_="h5 font-weight-normal mb-1").text.strip()
        animes_url=f'https://animego.org/{article.get("href")}'
        print(f"{anime_title}|{animes_url}")
get_first_anime()
```

что делать?
вот код с сайта
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Перебираете `"div", class_="animes-list-item media"`, а у него не будет атрибута `href` - это у тега `a`. Поэтому, `article.get("href")` возвращает `None`

Добавьте поиск тега `a` от текущего элемента:

```
animes_url = article.select_one('a')['href']
```

Comment: спасибо большое, помогли)

Comment: @dori, пожалуйста, и не забудьте [проголосовать и принять ответ](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/tour) :)